# Stop Chrome from trying to always update Java and Silverlight when running applets/plugins?

Tags: java, silverlight, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have recently added a Silverlight based plugin (Plupload) that works great except for one issue:

If you try to use it in Chrome your browser will popup with the message "Silverlight was blocked because it is out of date".

I appreciate Google trying to force users to update (which they otherwise never ever do) but this has single handedly tripled our customer support load.  Does anybody know of a way to force it to run in Chrome via Javascript/Html code?

We have seen the same issue with many sites using Java applets.  As Oracle constantly has minor updates it seems near impossible to stay "up to date" so effectively you asked to upgrade 9/10 times.

Comment: Since security issues are some of the main reasons for updating, I find it unlikely that there would be an officially-supported way to force an applet to run anyway from within the untrusted code. That seems like it would be a security issue.

Comment: Chrome is [deprecating NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) support and will soon not support Silverlight or Java at all.